# Numpy "put_along_axis", but add to existing values rather than just put (similar to scatter_add in PyTorch)

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

Is there a way to use `np.put_along_axis` but have it add to the existing values rather than replace?

For example, in PyTorch this could be implemented as:

```
import torch
frame = torch.zeros(3,2, dtype=torch.double)
updates = torch.tensor([[5,5], [10,10], [3,3]], dtype=torch.double)
indices = torch.tensor([[1,1], [1,1], [2,2]])

frame.scatter_add(0, indices, updates)
OUTPUT: [[0, 0], [15,15], [3,3]]
```

Numpy's `put_along_axis` would give:

```
import numpy as np
frame = np.zeros(3,2)
updates = np.array([[5,5], [10,10], [3,3]])
indices = np.array([[1,1], [1,1], [2,2]])

np.put_along_axis(frame, indices, update)
OUTPUT: [[0, 0],[10, 10], [3,3]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.add.at`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html), but you need to build additional column indices:

```
>>> frame = np.zeros((3, 2))
>>> updates = np.array([[5,5], [10,10], [3,3]])
>>> indices = np.array([[1,1], [1,1], [2,2]])
>>> np.add.at(frame, (indices, np.arange(frame.shape[1])), updates)
>>> frame
array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [15., 15.],
       [ 3.,  3.]])
```